# What would cause WinForms richTextBox.DataBindings.Add() to throw a Null Reference Exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have scratched my head on this for a while and just can't figure it out. I even spun up a brand new test project and cannot reproduce the error that I'm getting in my primary project.

The code in question is this:

```
private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("Text", _gizmo, nameof(_gizmo.MyProp));
    richRmDesc.DataBindings.Add(myBinding); //NullReference exception occurs on this line
}
```

I checked in Debugger.

- myBinding is NOT null.
- _gizmo is a brand new Gizmo object.  It's NOT null.
- _gizmo.MyProp is a string.  It's got text in it.
- Even richRmDesc.DataBindings is NOT null.  I can inspect all the fields
  and properties of the DataBindings member without issue.

The error has me completely stumped.
I've tried to simplify my form and startup code as much as possible, short of completely demolishing everything I've built on it (which I'm going to try next, but it's going to be slow and painful).

Does anybody know of a possible reason on why I'd get a Null reference exception on the DataBindings line when none of the items are even null?

Comment: Can you create a repro for this?

Comment: "none of the items are even null" does not guarantee the absence of exceptions, it could be caused by other methods meanwhile invoked inside `Add()`

Comment: I don&#39;t remember if the bindings are already initialized during form_load event. Try moving this code to an event later in the form lifecycle. Try moving this code to the Form_Shown event handler.

Comment: @mangusta Excellent tip! Yes that was indeed the case. Explanation is in my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the `NullReferenceException` is raised somewhere else. In Form.Load, usually, the exceptions generated there get eaten up  and the code execution *jumps*. Move the code in Form.Shown and see what happens (the `null` object should be referenced in the exception details, though).

Comment: @Jimi That is a great tip. I actually thought of that and tried it first, and I got exactly the same behavior!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I *thought* it would be a big deal to demolish my form components. It was in fact extremely easy with minimal refactoring (pays to write well-abstracted code).

I reduced the culprit to this line in the form class generated by the Designer:

```
this.richRmDesc.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.RichDesc_TextChanged);
```

So when I looked at the RichDesc_TextChanged event method, I discovered that it was invoking another method that was referencing a null collection because it had not yet been initialized. This was in some run-of-the-mill logic in the form itself.

For whatever reason, the debugger was completely unable to show me that the exception was actually happening in the TextChanged event. It wasn't even giving me an indication that the event was firing, though it makes sense that it would fire immediately upon binding.

I fixed the initiailization bug pertaining to the TextChanged event logic and now everything is fine.

I'm guessing that the debugger could not detect this event bug because it was happening on another thread??? Not sure really. Comments are welcome.

Comment: It happens sometimes. I found the VS2017 debugger less accurate than VS2008, the best IDE of all time...

Comment: One tip - [set the debugger to break as soon as the exception is thrown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown), i.e. before any handlers (or indeed `catch` blocks) are invoked. I find this very useful for tracking down NullReferenceExceptions.